# When balancing equations, how do we handle chemicals in different states of matter?

Tags: stoichiometry

Balancing chemical equations such as $$\mathrm{H_2 + O_2 \to H_2O}$$ or $$\mathrm{NaHCO_3 + H_3C_6H_5O_7 \to Na_3C_6H_5O_7 + H_2O + CO_2}$$ seems to be easy enough by finding the coefficients of each chemical. However, I have no idea when the states of the chemicals are introduced. For example, I can balance the equation $$\mathrm{Mg_3N_2 + H_2O \to NH_3 + Mg(OH)_2}$$ but I don't know how to balance it if the states are introduced such that it becomes $$\mathrm{Mg_3N_2 (s) + H_2O (l) \to NH_3 (g) + Mg(OH)_2 (s)}.$$

---

Is balancing equations without the states the same as balancing equations with states?

Comment: Ignore the states. They do not enter into balancing. Only mass balance counts i.e., the number of atoms on the left must equal the number of atoms on the right of the same element.

Comment: @M.Farooq Does this mean that the states are included for clarity, but does not really affect the balancing?

Comment: The matter state does not matter. It is the atom inventory that matters. Atoms do not transmute with change of matter state. There is observed no nuclear explosion when water freezes or ice melts.